# Normality of $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]/I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, reference-request, commutative-algebra

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69566/when-is-an-affine-algebra-normal) question says the following: "I was looking at results that give necessary (and possibly sufficient) conditions on an ideal $I$ in the ring $R=k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ such that $R/I$ is normal. I don't know if there is a standard result about this, but any references either way would be appreciated."

My question:

> Could one please explain or give a reference to the results the above quoted question refers to?
> I am not familiar with such results (the answer to that question elaborates on that topic, but I am still a little confused about what those known results really are).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Most commutative algebra books that I know have results related to your question with Serre's characterization of normality. For instance, I think it is in around Ch 16 of Eisunbud's commutative algebra book.

Comment: Thank you. Any further elaboration is welcome.